# Using REST APIs

Tags: gerrit

I am new to gerrit. I am using gerrit V. 2.6 . I want to use gerrit REST APIs in my python script. But not able to figure out how to use it. I tried below code but getting errors.

```
curl --digest --user user:password http://server/a/changes/path/to/project~branch~change_id/rebase
```

getting error :

401 Authorization Required

## Authorization Required

This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.

Am I missing something.??

Comment: I think you need to enable API access in Gerrit for the user.

Answer (score 9):

Are you using the correct username:password combination?  This isn't your network password - it is the HTTP password that gerrit generates.  You can find it by going to Settings->HTTP Password.  If the password box is blank, click the button to have Gerrit generate a new password.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! Had no idea that http://server/login form takes different credentials than the REST API's HTTP digest.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using pygerrit. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pygerrit/0.2.1

I think it has some APIs to easily access gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ramraj mentioned, you can try using [pygerrit](https://github.com/sonyxperiadev/pygerrit) or [pygerrit2](https://github.com/dpursehouse/pygerrit2).

And I provide some examples that how I use gerrit REST APIs in my python script.

Here is the code.

```
auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password) 
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='http://review.xxxxxx.com:8080', auth=auth)
```

Query changes by change number.

```
info = rest.get("/changes/?q=change:{}".format(change_number))
change_id = info[0]['change_id']
subject = info[0]['subject']
```

Query changes by commit id.

```
info = rest.get("/changes/?q=commit:{}".format(commit_id))
change_id = info[0]['change_id']
subject = info[0]['subject']
```

Revert a change.

```
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'} 
query = "/changes/" + str(change_number) + "/revert" 
my_data = {"message": "{}".format("Revert "+str(subject))} 
rest.post(query, data=json.dumps(my_data), timeout=30, headers=headers)
```

Review a change

```
headers = {'content-disposition': 'attachment', 'content-type': 'application/json'} 
query = "/changes/" + str(change_number) + "/revisions/current/review" 
my_data = { "labels": {"Code-Review": "+2", "Verified": "+1"} } 
rest.post(query, data=json.dumps(my_data), timeout=30, headers=headers)
```