# Gerrit Authentication required

Tags: gerrit

I'm working on some automation for Gerrit. I have used following API to check access

```
curl -X POST --digest -k --user username:password https://gitAccess/access/
```

But returns authentication required. Can you please help me

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Have you looked at the [REST API documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication)? Have you tried `/a/access`?
Why the oracle tag?

Comment: Thanks for your response. After adding what you specified I got Unauthorized.. i should be admin?

Comment: StephenKing, Can you please help me on this

Comment: I did not follow this any further as it also did not work for me initially. I now gave it a try once more and - although we're using HTTP auth - I had to generate a HTTP password in Gerrit (and remove the `--digest`). This one worked then. So basically, I had the same problem as [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21544870/using-rest-apis). Does that work for you?

Answer (score 7):

3 things to note as I was also getting an "unauthorized" when trying to access Gerrit APIs

1. Make sure you have your HTTP password. This is different from the
   password you use to login to Gerrit. To get it, go to `gerrit ->
   click on your username -> Settings -> HTTP Password -> Click on
   generate password`. Use this password when making HTTP requests
2. Prefix `/a` to the endpoint URL as mentioned [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api.html#authentication). For example `/changes` becomes `/a/changes` when using authentication
3. Use the `--digest` option if you are using `curl` as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/BsCU5X1Q65s)

Example

```
curl --digest -u <USERNAME> -i -H "Accept: application/json" "https://<GERRIT SERVER>/a/changes"
# curl will prompt you for the password. You can also do it as below
curl --digest --user <USERNAME:PASSWORD> -i -H "Accept: application/json" "https://<GERRIT SERVER>/a/changes"
```

Comment: the curl shell scrip has an error :

Comment: @user3033075 can you help specify what the error is? or what error message you see?

Comment: I am sorry. this answer is right . my problem is that when I use the review api of gerrit. I just copy the code here to post data to my gerrit server. I don't get any error but it does  not work to review code by "+2".
finally,I find the error is  that I miss a header whose content is: "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" . as this reason , I didn't know what's wrong , because everything looks good but it has no effect. After I add the additional header , it works. 
So, it's my own problem. not this answer. I am  so sorry for that.